# How to create dynamic routes in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

Is it possible to create a CMS with ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages? Assuming there is an entity "Page" that allows an admin to create pages, example of these pages would be:

- example.com/home
- example.com/about
- example.com/contact

If these pages are stored in a database of any type, and retrieved by ASP.NET, how can the routing system build these routes at runtime? Is it even possible?